# TypeError when trying to iterate through Map elements

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to iterate over elements of, what I think is, a `Map` object and getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cr.forEach is not a function
   at exports.onNewOrder.functions.database.ref.onCreate.event (/user_code/index.js:122:12)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
   at next (native)
   at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
   at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
   at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
   at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:728:24
   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Here is the code I am running from within Google Cloud Function:

```
function logMapElements(value, key, mapObj) {
    console.log(`m[${key}] = ${value}`);
}    

exports.onNewOrder = functions.database.ref('/orders/{orderId}').onCreate(event => {

    const data = event.val();
    const cr = data.crs;
    console.log(cr);

    cr.forEach(logMapElements);
}
```

This is what printed in the log by `console.log(c)`:

```
{ cr_36446aba912c45d0956e57cbf0a4e165: 1, cr_d46f4c12119e45478a0aa2867df55e09: 1 }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: cr is object, since it is object, you cant use forEach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it like :

```
  Object.keys(object).map(function(objectKey, index) {
  var value = object[objectKey];
  console.log(value);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answers from Sidhanshu_, user9977547, and Fabien Greard all may work, I consider using Firebase's built-in `DataSnapshot.forEach` method to be more idiomatic:

```
exports.onNewOrder = functions.database.ref('/orders/{orderId}').onCreate(event => {
    event.child("crs").forEach(child => {
      console.log(child.val());
    });
}
```

While the result between `Array.forEach()` and `DataSnapshot.forEach()` will be the same here, it has a subtle difference in some other cases. When you query data from the Firebase Database, `DataSnapshot.forEach()` will iterate the children in the requested order, while you'll typically have lost that order by the time you get to `Array.forEach()`. To avoid subtle bugs, I recommend using `DataSnapshot.forEach()` for any data from the Firebase Database.

Answer (score 1):

`forEach()` only work on array, `cr` is an `object`.

You could use `map()` instead. Or convert your obect into an array with `Object.values()` (also see `Object.keys()`, `Object.entries()`

Answer (score 1):

Because cr is not an array you
can’t use methods of an array with it. Try to use use a `for (bar propertyName in object)` loop here.

```
for(var id in cr){
   var value = cr[id]
   ...
}
```